# Location of bootstrap.properties file on liberty profile

Tags: websphere, configuration-files, websphere-liberty

I am really new to Liberty and I am not able to locate `bootstrap.properties` file, Can anyone please let me know where will I can find this file. Please give a generic path so that I can check once. Really appreciate all your help.

Answer (score 2):

The `bootstrap.properties` should be located in the `${server.config.dir}`  (e.g. `wlp\usr\servers\serverName`) folder. It is not present by default, so you will have to create it manually.

See also:

- [Specifying Liberty profile bootstrap properties](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.iseries.doc/ae/twlp_inst_bootstrap.html?cp=SSEQTP_8.5.5%2F2-3-11-0-2-3&lang=en)
- [Using variables in configuration files](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/twlp_setup_vars.html?cp=SSEQTP_8.5.5%2F1-3-11-0-3-2-3-1&lang=en)
- [Liberty profile: Directory locations and properties](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/rwlp_dirs.html?cp=SSEQTP_8.5.5%2F1-3-11-0-2-0&lang=en)

Comment: I am not able to view any files on this location, however can this be configured with any other name as well please confirm.

Comment: @djrecker As I wrote - **there is no file there by default** - if you need one, you have to create it. I dont understand, what you mean by other name. Directory name is **your server name**, so it can be different in your case, but file name must be `bootstrap.properties`. Please check the second link for other configuration files you can put there.

Comment: @Gas, do u know how to check why my bootstrap.properties value does not take effect to my mfp server?

Comment: @PanadolChong I suggest you to create separate question with detailed description of your problem as it is hard to tell just from your comment.